# Correct way to consume GitVersion injected version metadata

Tags: c#, gitversion

I want to show my app's semver in a TextBlock. For that, I have this method:

```
private string GetVersionDescription()
    {
        // Semantic version provided by GitVersion
        var appName = "AppDisplayName".GetLocalized();
        var appVersion = GitVersionInformation.SemVer;

        return $"{appName} - {appVersion}";
    }
```

When I compile, however, I get this error:

```
The "CompileXaml" task returned false but did not log an error.
```

What I'm doing wrong and what's the correct way to consume the injected metadata?

Thanks your your time.

Comment: Since the error relates to compiling your XAML, why are you confident that the call to the `SemVer` property is causing the error?

Comment: Hi, @JeremyCaney. The original code `var appVersion = Package.Current.Id.Version; return $"{appVersion.Major}.{appVersion.Minor}.{appVersion.Build}.{appVersion.Revision}";` doesn't produce the error. `var appVersion = GitVersionInformation.SemVer; return $"{appVersion}";` does, therefore my guess.